# how can i use custom field in query post

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

I want to get all featured items using query post. featured is meta_key using custom field plugin.

I tried bellow,but it failed

```
$featured_item = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&cat=3&meta_key=>Featured List&meta_value=>Yes');
```

my wp version is 3.1.3

**EDIT:**

```
$arg2 = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>'5',
    'cat'=>'3',
    'orderby'=>'rand',
    'meta_query'=> array(
        'key'=>'Featured List',
        'value'=>'Yes',
        'compare'=>'LIKE'
    )
);

$featured_random_item = new WP_Query($arg2);
```

This query also failed.

How can i do this

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `meta_query` needs to be a *nested* array, like so;

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'cat' => '3',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => 'Featured List',
            'value' => 'Yes'        
        )
    )
);
```

And I get the feeling you don't actually need a `LIKE` match - this'll perform a loose comparison, and isn't as efficient as an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for WP_Query is here:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

You should use the array syntax, as it will make things clearer for you.

Comment: will you explain with examples? already i saw that class reference page but am not getting idea,how to solve this !!

Comment: Thanks for the respomse,  I tried that query,but still it fails. look at my edit,There is what i tried . can you tell me whats wrong in query.

Comment: @ramkumar - there are examples on the Codex page.